# Python3 tkinter askdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Hi I have this code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from pytube import YouTube

class download_youtube_video:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ydownload4u = Tk()
        self.ydownload4u.title("Youtube download for you")
        self.ydownload4u.geometry("400x400+600+250")

        label_title = Label(self.ydownload4u, text="Youtube Download For You", font="times 25 bold underline")
        label_title.place(x=40, y=10)

        label_link = Label(self.ydownload4u, text="Please enter link of video Youtube:", font="times 15")
        label_link.place(x=35, y=70)

        self.box_link = Entry(self.ydownload4u, width="35")
        self.box_link.place(x=30, y=100)

        label_save = Label(self.ydownload4u, text="Please select where save file:", font="times 15")
        label_save.place(x=35, y=150)


        self.save_location = Button(self.ydownload4u, text="save as", command=lambda :self.save_as())
        self.save_location.place(x=260, y=135)
        self.save_location.config(height = 3, width = 10)

        self.label_show_loction = Label(self.ydownload4u, text="You are save file here: ")
        self.label_show_loction.place(x=35, y=220)

        self.label_show_loction1 = Label(self.ydownload4u, text= lambda :self.save_as())
        self.label_show_loction1.place(x=175, y=220)



        self.ydownload4u.mainloop()

    def save_as(self):
        self.save = filedialog.askdirectory()
```

I want show in self.label_show_loction1 the location of self.save
I try put self.save in self.label_show_loction1 he give me massage: 140544723958912
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a string variable from tk and add to your Label, Button or any kind of component as a textvariable like:

```
self.loc1 = tk.StringVar(value="")
self.label_show_loction1 = Label(self.ydownload4u, textvariable=self.loc1)
```

To change variable value you can do something like:

```
tk.Button(self.frameName, text="save as", command=self.save_as)

def save_as(self):
    save = filedialog.askdirectory()
    self.loc1.set(save)
```

When you click the button the variable will be updated and will be shown at the location you put at.

Comment: For convenience do not use lambda for command arguments if you are not going to send arguments for that function.

Comment: Ty for tip I will remove lambda if I not send arguments for that function